# Unit testing custom RoleProvider with Moq?

Tags: unit-testing, moq, roleprovider

I created a custom RoleProvider in a custom library. I would like to unit test it. Via Moq I created a fake HttpContextBase. How to pass this to the to be tested RoleProvider?

The Identity is a custom test [implementation class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187890/moq-custom-iidentity). This works fine. I only don't know how to pass in the fake context in my provider. This is not an MVC application but standard Webforms if that's information needed.

Grz, Kris.

Comment: At the moment I'm giving this a try: http://haacked.com/archive/2005/06/11/Simulating_HttpContext.aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Dependency Injection (DI) and pass it through your custom RoleProvider's constructor.

```
public MyRoleProvider(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    // ...
}
```

This would allow you to pass the Moq instance via the constructor.

Comment: Save it as a member variable.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. The roleprovider can't be hassled with (codewise). Is there another workaround possible?

Comment: If you can't create a RoleProvider via code, you may alternatively be able to use a ServiceLocator to get an instance of HttpContextBase for you from the inside. It's not as nice, but sometimes it is necessary.