# How to test HttpApplication events in IHttpModules

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq, httpmodule

I am writing `HttpModule` and need to test it, I am using `C#`, `.NET4.5.2`, `NUnit` and `Moq`.

Method I am trying to test is `Context_BeginRequest`:

```
public class XForwardedForRewriter : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += Context_BeginRequest;
    }

    public void Context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) { ... }
}
```

`sender` here is [`HttpApplication`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication(v=vs.110).aspx) and this is where the problems start,... one can create instance of `HttpApplication` however there is no way to set `HttpContext` since it is read only and there is no way to pass it in (via constructor or something alike)...

I don't have `VS2015 Ultimate` and can't use `Microsoft.Fakes` ([Shims](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175(v=vs.110).aspx)), and ATM the only solution for this I have found [is to create a wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182338/unit-testing-an-httpapplication) which doesn't sound like most straightforward solution....

When I think about this I am sure that someone has already ran into this exact problem (as every time one is writing `HttpModule` in TDD he will need to mock `HttpApplication` or do some workaround)

**How does one test events `IHttpModules`?  Is there a way of Mocking HttpApplication?** preferebly with `Moq`.

**EDIT:** Here is the code I am trying to test... it's header re-writer from `PROXY v2` binary to good old `X-Forwarded-For`...

```
public class XForwardedForRewriter : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    byte[] proxyv2HeaderStartRequence = new byte[12] { 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x51, 0x55, 0x49, 0x54, 0x0A };

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += Context_BeginRequest;
    }

    public void Context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var request = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context.Request;

        var proxyv2header = request.BinaryRead(12);
        if (!proxyv2header.SequenceEqual(proxyv2HeaderStartRequence))
        {
            request.Abort();
        }
        else
        {
            var proxyv2IpvType = request.BinaryRead(5).Skip(1).Take(1).Single();
            var isIpv4 = new byte[] { 0x11, 0x12 }.Contains(proxyv2IpvType);
            var ipInBinary = isIpv4 ? request.BinaryRead(12) : request.BinaryRead(36);
            var ip = Convert.ToString(ipInBinary);

            var headers = request.Headers;
            Type hdr = headers.GetType();
            PropertyInfo ro = hdr.GetProperty("IsReadOnly",
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);

            ro.SetValue(headers, false, null);

            hdr.InvokeMember("InvalidateCachedArrays",
                BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                null, headers, null);

            hdr.InvokeMember("BaseAdd",
                BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                null, headers,
                new object[] { "X-Forwarded-For", new ArrayList { ip } });

            ro.SetValue(headers, true, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test? Show the SUT and maybe a work around can be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following shows a potential work around for making the above case test-able

```
public class XForwardedForRewriter : IHttpModule {
    public void Dispose() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    byte[] proxyv2HeaderStartRequence = new byte[12] { 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x51, 0x55, 0x49, 0x54, 0x0A };

    public void Init(HttpApplication context) {
        context.BeginRequest += Context_BeginRequest;
    }

    public Func<object, HttpRequestBase> GetRequest = (object sender) => {
        return new HttpRequestWrapper(((HttpApplication)sender).Context.Request);
    };

    public void Context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var request = GetRequest(sender);

        var proxyv2header = request.BinaryRead(12);
        if (!proxyv2header.SequenceEqual(proxyv2HeaderStartRequence)) {
            request.Abort();
        } else {
            var proxyv2IpvType = request.BinaryRead(5).Skip(1).Take(1).Single();
            var isIpv4 = new byte[] { 0x11, 0x12 }.Contains(proxyv2IpvType);
            var ipInBinary = isIpv4 ? request.BinaryRead(12) : request.BinaryRead(36);
            var ip = Convert.ToString(ipInBinary);

            var headers = request.Headers;
            var hdr = headers.GetType();
            var ro = hdr.GetProperty("IsReadOnly",
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);

            ro.SetValue(headers, false, null);

            hdr.InvokeMember("InvalidateCachedArrays",
                BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                null, headers, null);

            hdr.InvokeMember("BaseAdd",
                BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                null, headers,
                new object[] { "X-Forwarded-For", new ArrayList { ip } });

            ro.SetValue(headers, true, null);
        }
    }
}
```

The tests would end up like

```
[TestClass]
public class XForwardedForRewriterTests {

    [TestMethod]
    public void Request_Should_Abort() {
        //Arrange
        var request = Mock.Of<HttpRequestBase>();

        var sut = new XForwardedForRewriter();
        //replace with mock request for test
        sut.GetRequest = (object sender) => request;

        //Act
        sut.Context_BeginRequest(new object(), EventArgs.Empty);

        //Assert
        var mockRequest = Mock.Get(request);
        mockRequest.Verify(m => m.Abort(), Times.AtLeastOnce);
    }


    [TestMethod]
    public void Request_Should_Forward() {
        //Arrange
        var request = Mock.Of<HttpRequestBase>();

        var mockRequest = Mock.Get(request);
        //setup mocked request with desired behavior for test
        var proxyv2HeaderStartRequence = new byte[12] { 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x51, 0x55, 0x49, 0x54, 0x0A };
        mockRequest
            .Setup(m => m.BinaryRead(12))
            .Returns(proxyv2HeaderStartRequence);

        var fakeProxyv2IpvType = new byte[5] { 0x00, 0x12, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
        mockRequest
            .Setup(m => m.BinaryRead(5))
            .Returns(fakeProxyv2IpvType);

        var headers = new NameValueCollection();
        mockRequest.Setup(m => m.Headers).Returns(headers);

        var sut = new XForwardedForRewriter();
        //replace with mock request for test
        sut.GetRequest = (object sender) => request;

        //Act
        sut.Context_BeginRequest(new object(), EventArgs.Empty);

        //Assert
        //...check request headers
        var xForwardedFor = headers["X-Forwarded-For"];
        Assert.IsNotNull(xForwardedFor);
    }

}
```

One observation of the Sut is that the `ip` resolves to `"System.Byte[]"` which I believe is not expected behavior. Recheck the `proxyv2HeaderStartRequence`.

Apart from adding the Factory method to access the request, the rest of the code under test remained the same. Observe for the actual implementation, how the request was wrapped in a `HttpRequestBase` derived class which allowed for a mock to be swapped in its place for testing.

This should now allow for the application of TDD with the module.

Comment: Hi Nkosi, this does work indeed, very clever I must say. Thanks