# How to mock out the server transfer method using shims and or Moq

Tags: c#, module, mocking, moq, shim

I am trying to mock up the following Transfer request.

I have tried using Moq but it doesn't like the fact that it is a method call. Any ideas?

I have tried using shims but it hasn't exactly made sense to me. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4e423407-300d-46ba-bfc9-30465fb18f07/how-to-fake-httpcontextcurrent-using-shim?forum=vstest 
I tried mocking http context this way but it didn't work either.
https://justinchmura.com/2014/06/26/mock-httpcontext/

```
public class MyModule1 : IHttpModule
{
    /// <summary>
    /// You will need to configure this module in the Web.config file of your
    /// web and register it with IIS before being able to use it. For more information
    /// see the following link: https://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=8101007
    /// </summary>
    #region IHttpModule Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        //clean-up code here.
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        // Below is an example of how you can handle LogRequest event and provide 
        // custom logging implementation for it
        context.LogRequest += new EventHandler(OnLogRequest);
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(OnBeginRequest);
    }

    private void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        onbegin(new HttpContextWrapper(((HttpApplication)sender).Context));


    }

    private void onbegin(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        // other header stuff goes here
        context.Server.TransferRequest("bobsyouruncle", true);
    }

    #endregion

    public void OnLogRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        //custom logging logic can go here
    }
```

Comment: Because you are using concrete classes in your module (i.e. HttpApplication) and they're all sealed, without Microsoft Fakes you're really out of luck. If you can switch to be using more modern HttpContextBase etc. like you do in the `onbegin` method, you could Mock those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to an approach I took in an answer provided here

[How to test HttpApplication events in IHttpModules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42391805/5233410)

You can create a factory method/function that wraps the current tightly coupled implementation concerns in abstractions that would allow for better mocking and testability

Refactored module

```
public class MyModule1 : IHttpModule {
    public void Dispose() {
        //clean-up code here.
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication application) {
        // Below is an example of how you can handle LogRequest event and provide 
        // custom logging implementation for it
        application.LogRequest += new EventHandler(OnLogRequest);
        application.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(OnBeginRequest);
    }

    public Func<object, HttpContextBase> GetContext = (object sender) => {
        return new HttpContextWrapper(((HttpApplication)sender).Context);
    };

    public void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var context = GetContext(sender);
        onbegin(context);
    }

    private void onbegin(HttpContextBase context) {
        // other header stuff goes here
        context.Server.TransferRequest("bobsyouruncle", true);
    }

    public void OnLogRequest(Object source, EventArgs e) {
        //custom logging logic can go here
    }

    //...
}
```

The `GetContext` factory function can be replaced when testing to use a mock.

For example

```
[TestMethod]
public void Server_Should_Transfer() {
    //Arrange
    var server = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();
    var context = new Mock.<HttpContextBase>();
    context.Setup(_ => _.Server).Returns(server.Object);

    var sut = new MyModule1();

    //replace with mock context for test
    sut.GetContext = (object sender) => context.Object;

    //Act
    sut.OnBeginRequest(new object(), EventArgs.Empty);

    //Assert
    server.Verify(_ => _.TransferRequest("bobsyouruncle", true), Times.AtLeastOnce);
}
```